# Tilebased boardgame dicenumber restriction (Incremental algorithms)

Tags: c#

Developing a 2D tile-based "boardgame" I'm struggling with the restriction I have to make, when a player rolls the dice(Move 5 tiles if you land a 5 etc.)

I'm trying to use the following logic:
[image]

- Start on starting point
- Check the position to the sides, above and below
- Check if the neighbour tiles are walkable, if they are, change them to reachable
- Go to neighbour tile, repeat

I've been looking on A* and D* pathing, but it's a new subject to me and they seem more focused on getting from point A to B, not "reach" which is what I need.

How do I do this through code?

I created a 2D array from an array which was holding my tile(I need a normal array of the tilemap for another purpose):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 33; j++)
            {
                tileMap[i, j] = goTile[i * 33  + j];
            }
        }
```

I now use the tileMap as my positiong factor, e.g. my players current position is tileMap[2,4].

I then tried to develop a function:

```
void pathFinding(Vector2 playerPosition, int diceNumber)
    {
        GameObject currentPos = tileMap[(int)playerPosition.x, (int)playerPosition.y];

        for (int i = 0; i < diceNumber; i++) {
                if (tileMap[(int)playerPosition.x + 1, (int)playerPosition.y].tag == "walkableGrid")
                {
                    tileMap[(int)playerPosition.x + 1, (int)playerPosition.y].gameObject.tag = "reachable";
                    playerPosition.x++;
                }

                if (tileMap[(int)playerPosition.x  - 1, (int)playerPosition.y].tag == "walkableGrid")
                {
                    playerPosition.x--;
                }

                if (tileMap[(int)playerPosition.x, (int)playerPosition.y + 1].tag == "walkableGrid")
                {
                    playerPosition.y++;
                }

                if (tileMap[(int)playerPosition.x, (int)playerPosition.y - 1].tag == "walkableGrid")
                {
                    playerPosition.y--;
                }
            }
    }
```

But as finishing this (if it even would work), would require MANY lines of code, and I believe there's a swifter method using a nested for loop maybe?

Comment: So... what do you expect us to answer here?

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: Show us some code of the data structure, otherwise it will be very hard to guess at a correct solution. Also, have you tried to code anything yourself?

Comment: Added how I set up my tilemap and my own attempt on the algorithm.

Comment: It doesn't look like this has anything to do with Unity. You could solve this problem with a command line interface in any programming language.

Answer (score 2):

```
//I have now edited the code to better reflect your real data

public void ShowMoves(Vector2 playerPosition, int diceNumber, bool[] blocks)
{

    int x = (int)playerPosition.x;
    int y = (int)playerPosition.y;

    if(tileMap.GetUpperBound(0) < x + 1)
    {
        if(tileMap[x + 1, y].tag == "walkableGrid" && blocks[0])
        {
            /*Light up the tile*/
            if(diceNumber > 0)
                ShowMoves(new Vector2(x + 1, y), diceNumber - 1, new bool[] { x != tileMap.GetUpperBound(0), false, y != tileMap.GetUpperBound(1), y != 0 });
        }
    }

    if(x - 1 >= 0)
    {
        if(tileMap[x - 1, y].tag == "walkableGrid" && blocks[1])
        {
            /*Light up the tile*/
            if(diceNumber > 0)
                ShowMoves(new Vector2(x - 1, y), diceNumber - 1, new bool[] { false, x != 0, y != tileMap.GetUpperBound(1), y != 0 });
        }
    }

    if(tileMap.GetUpperBound(1) < y + 1)
    {
        if(tileMap[x, y + 1].tag == "walkableGrid" && blocks[2])
        {
            /*Light up the tile*/
            if(diceNumber > 0)
                ShowMoves(new Vector2(x, y + 1), diceNumber - 1, new bool[] { x != tileMap.GetUpperBound(0), x != 0, y != tileMap.GetUpperBound(1), false });
        }
    }

    if(y - 1 >= 0)
    {
        if(tileMap[x, y - 1].tag == "walkableGrid" && blocks[3])
        {
            /*Light up the tile*/
            if(diceNumber > 0)
                ShowMoves(new Vector2(x, y - 1), diceNumber - 1, new bool[] { x != tileMap.GetUpperBound(0), x != 0, false, y != 0 });
        }
    }
}
```

This code might not compile, but it's an example to help you along - it will loop until there are no available moves, and exhaust every option. It will also not go back on itself due to the `blocks` boolean array. The input format would be the position they're at two ints, one for x and one for y, the tiles available, the number of moves left in their roll, and the block available from the beginning (always `new bool[] {true, true, true, true}`

**Be careful, there may be errors in my code, I wrote it in SO and have no clue how well it runs, if it runs at all or anything. Even if it does not, it should be a good starting point for you to create your logic and code it all**

**EDIT: Code has been changed so that it better fits how your code looks and the data types it uses**

To avoid always calling the method by inputting a `blocks` variable of `new bool[] {true, true, true, true};` you can make it an optional operator by making this the method parameters

```
public void ShowMoves(Vector2 playerPosition, int diceNumber, bool[] blocks = new bool[] {true, true, true, true})
```